# Veryfying if a certain key is in a hash table

Tags: c, hash, hashtable

So, I need to make a function that given a certain hash table, and a key, verifies if there is an object with the same key. So far, what I have is:

```
int hash_exists(hash_table td, const char *key)
{
    element *temp = NULL;
    int i = 0;

    if (td == NULL)
        return INVALID_HASHTABLE;

    i = td->hfunc(key, td->size);

    for (i=0; i<td->size;i++)
    {
        temp = td->elements[i];

        while (temp!=NULL)
        {
            if (strcmp(temp->obj->key, key)!)
                return INEXISTENT_HASHTABLE;

            else
                temp = temp->next;
        }
}
    return EXISTING_HASHTABLE;
}
```

But, running a test program, it says that it must return `INEXISTENTE_HASHTABLE` when the value doesn't exist in the hash table.

BTW, `hfunc(key, td->size)` returns the value of the hash associated with the string/key. It is very specific of this problem, so just ignore it. And,

```
typedef struct
{
    char key[KEY_SIZE];
    char value[SIZE_VALUE];
} objet;


typedef struct elem
{
    objet* obj;
    struct elem * next;
} element;


struct hash_table
{
    hash_func *hfunc;
    element **elements;
    int size;
}

typedef struct hash_table *hash_table;
```

I would really like to know what I'm doing wrong, and if someone could correct my code, I'd appreciate it. I did search the forum for something that would help me, but didn't find anything. Thanks.

Comment: What is this: `if (strcmp(temp->obj->key, key)!)`, use either `if (strcmp(temp->obj->key, key))` or `if (!strcmp(temp->obj->key, key))`. You are using `!` operator in wrong way.

Comment: You are getting `i` as `i = td->hfunc(key, td->size);` then doing:

`for (i=0; i<td->size;i++)`, What is use of value returned by `hfunc`?

Comment: Think you have messed the return codes, 1st return should return `EXISTING_HASHTABLE` and 2nd `INEXISTING_HASHTABLE`.

Comment: Why are you looping through the entire hash table, taking O(`n`) time as if it were an array, instead of using the table's search-method thus taking only O(`ln(n)`)?.. Your professor is likely to deduct points for this even if you implement the loop correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You have reversed the return values. Also the if condition needed a slight modification:

```
int hash_exists(hash_table td, const char *key)
{
    element *temp = NULL;
    int i = 0;

    if (td == NULL)
        return INVALID_HASHTABLE;

    i = td->hfunc(key, td->size);

    for (i=0; i<td->size;i++)
    {
        temp = td->elements[i];

        while (temp!=NULL)
        {
            if (!strcmp(temp->obj->key, key)) {
                return EXISTING_HASHTABLE;     // Key found
            }
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        // Key not found
        return INEXISTENT_HASHTABLE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int hash_exists(hash_table td, const char *key)
{
    element *temp = NULL;
    int i = 0;

    if (td == NULL)
        return INVALID_HASHTABLE;

    i = td->hfunc(key, td->size);

    for (i=0; i<td->size;i++)
    {
        temp = td->elements[i];

        while (temp!=NULL)
        {
            if (!strcmp(temp->obj->key, key))
                return EXISTING_HASHTABLE;

            else
                temp = temp->next;
        }
}
    return INEXISTENT_HASHTABLE;
}
```

Comment: This just makes eclipse crash. I really don't know what's happening. Maybe it's an error with other functions of the same program. Or maybe I didn't specified well what the function should do?
It's supposed to verify if a value  exists in the hash table, given the key. I'm not sure if I made myself clear in the beginning.
@Klas Lindbäck

Answer (score 0):

```
int hash_exists(hash_table td, const char *key)
{
    element *temp = NULL;
    int i; // should be unsigned

    if (td == NULL)
        return INVALID_HASHTABLE;

    i = td->hfunc(key, td->size);

    for (temp = td->elements[i]; temp; temp = temp->next) {
            if ( !strcmp(temp->obj->key, key)) return EXISTING_HASHTABLE;    
            }
    return INEXISTENT_HASHTABLE;
}
```